# Python path broken on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

So I've had this problem for a while now where sometimes random commands with pip don't work. Just today I was trying to run the command:

```
$ python3 -m pip3 install --upgrade pip3
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9: No module named pip3
```

**EDIT** - I have tried:

```
$ python3 -m pip install -U pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (21.0.1)
$ python3 -m pip3 install --upgrade pip3
/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9: No module named pip3
```

Any idea what might be causing this and how to fix?

Comment: The _python module_ pip3 is not the same as the _command_ pip3.

Comment: To expand, `pip3` is an [entry point](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/entry-points/) for the `pip` module. There is no module `pip3`. Hence, you want `python3 -m pip install -U pip`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but when I ran that I still get the same error

Comment: That's not the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pip is already up-to-date. There is nothing to fix.

Comment: Thanks, I am just trying to figure out why I am still getting the no module named pip3 error. Is this expected?

Comment: Yes that's expected because pip3 isn't a module. The module is named "pip" and "pip3" is a command that just calls python3 pip.